# String based axis for jQuery Flot graphs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

How do I get non-numeric values on a Flot graph axis?

For example, on the Y-axis I would like to have (excuse the crappy graph):

```
/*
    A|
    B|          _/*----------*
    C|        _/              \
    D|      _/                 \
    E|    _/                    \
    F|   /                       \
    G|  *                         *
      --------------------------------
       100        200       300   400
```

The data I would provide will look like this:
var data = [[100, 'G'], [200, 'B'], [300, 'B'], [400, 'G']];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can feed a function to `tickFormatter` to markup an axis. Assuming `G = 0` and `A = 6`:

```
var data = [[100, 0], [200, 5], [300, 5], [400, 0]];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {
    yaxis: { tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
        return "GFEDCBA".charAt(v);
      }
    }
});
```

[image: Flot example]

The `charAt` function simply takes the the y-axis value (0, 5, 5, 0) and returns the letter from the string corresponding to that position.

Answer (score 6):

You can also associate text with a tick value, like this:

```
ticks: [[0, "G"], [1, "F"], [2, "E"], [3, "D"]], // so on
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is you can control it completely at runtime from your AJAX call (assuming you pass down the axis configuration using JSON), whereas the currently posted solution requires a hard-coded function.